# how to change war file directory in maven using terminal?

Tags: maven

I am able to create `war` file for Maven project in terminal by using following command `mvn package -Ddir="/home/myuser"`. War file is getting created in target folder of maven project but I need to create project war file in any local directory through terminal in ubuntu.

Please help me.

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>Simple_project</groupId>
  <artifactId>Project</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>Project Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>project</finalName>
  </build>  
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use maven `deploy` command to copy to `war` to your specified location

see below example

```
mvn  deploy:deploy-file -Durl=file://path//to//copy -DrepositoryId=com.example -Dfile=.//target//TestMaven-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar -Dversion=1.0  -DgroupId=com.example -DartifactId=test
```

also you can refer about maven deploy in more details [here](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/usage.html)

Comment: Thanks for your reply.